# An identity involving polylogarithms

Tags: combinatorial-identities, polylogarithms

Recall that
$$\mathrm{Li}_2(x):=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{x^n}{n^2}.$$
I have found the following identity:
\begin{equation}\begin{aligned}&\mathrm{Li}_2\left(\frac{-1-\sqrt{-7}}4\right)+\mathrm{Li}_2\left(\frac{-1+\sqrt{-7}}4\right)
\\&+\mathrm{Li}_2\left(\frac{3-\sqrt{-7}}8\right)+\mathrm{Li}_2\left(\frac{3+\sqrt{-7}}8\right)
\\&\qquad=\arctan^2\frac{\sqrt7}5-\frac{\log^22}4.
\end{aligned}\label{1}\tag{1}\end{equation}
This can be easily checked numerically.

**Question.** How to prove the identity \eqref{1}?

Your comments are welcome!

Comment: Take $z_0=\frac{5-i\sqrt{7}}{8}$, then the given expression is $2 \mathcal{Re}[\mathrm{Li}_2(1-z_0)+\mathrm{Li}_2(1-\frac{1}{z_0})]$. The explicit formula for this is on wikipedia page https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spence%27s_function. Using this we get the solution.

Comment: @AlapanDas Incidentally, we have the identities $\frac{5-\sqrt{-7}}8 = 2\left(\frac{-1+\sqrt{-7}}4\right)^3$, so it is almost a cube, while $\frac{3+\sqrt{-7}}8 = -\left(\frac{-1+\sqrt{-7}}4\right)^2$ is a square.

Answer (score 11):

I am elaborating my comment here: The expression given in the question can be written as $2\Re [\mathrm{Li}_2(\alpha) + \mathrm{Li}_2(\beta)]$ where $\alpha=\frac{-1+i\sqrt{7}}{8}, \beta=\frac{3-i\sqrt{7}}{8}$.

Now, take $z_0=\frac{5+i\sqrt{7}}{8}$. So, we have $\alpha=1-\frac{1}{z_0}$ and $\beta=1-z_0$. Having written this in a known form, we use the identity $\mathrm{Li}_2(1-z) + \mathrm{Li}_2(1-\frac{1}{z})=-\frac{(\ln z)^2}{2}$ which is mentioned in Wikipedia.

Hence we obtain the expression in question to be $-\Re [(\ln (\frac{5-i\sqrt{7}}{8}))^2]=\theta^2-\ln(\sqrt{2})^2$, where $\theta=-\arctan(\frac{\sqrt{7}}{5})$ is the argument of $z_0$.

Answer (score 2):

A quick remark on the linked [identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spence%27s_function#Identities) $\mathrm{Li}_2(1-z) + \mathrm{Li}_2(1-\frac{1}{z})=-\frac12 \log^2 z   $. Since from the  definition $\displaystyle \mathrm{Li}_2(1-z)=\int_1^z\frac{\log t}{1-t}dt$, it can be written
$$\int_1^z\frac{\log t}{1-t}dt+\int_1^\frac1z \frac{\log t}{1-t}dt+\frac12 \log^2 z=0,$$
and can be checked immediately by derivation.

Answer (score 1):

My way to go is to use the functional identities w.r.t. to the transformations $z\to 1/z$ and $z\to 1-z$, usually isolated in the world of the $K_3$-symbols. These identities are (i am citing [Zagier](https://people.mpim-bonn.mpg.de/zagier/files/doi/10.1007/978-3-540-30308-4_1/fulltext.pdf), §2, page 8):
$$
\begin{aligned}
\operatorname{Li}_2(z)
+
\operatorname{Li}_2\left(\frac 1z\right)
&=
-\frac{\pi^2}6-\frac 12\log^2(-z)\ ,
\\
\operatorname{Li}_2(z)
+
\operatorname{Li}_2(1-z)
&=
+\frac{\pi^2}6-\log (z)\log(1-z)\ .
\end{aligned}
$$
Let $a$ be $\sqrt{-7}$ for short, and the numbers $s,t;u,v$ be the numbers that appear in the OP formula $(1)$,
$$
s=-\frac 14(1+a)\ ,\ 
t=-\frac 14(1-a)\ ;\ 
u=\frac 18(3-a)\ ,\ 
v=\frac 18(3+a)\ .
$$
We use the equality
$$
1-\frac 1s=\frac 1v\ ,
$$
and proceed from now on in a natural manner. Explicit full computation:
$$
\begin{aligned}
\operatorname{Li}_2(s) +
\operatorname{Li}_2(v) 
&=
\operatorname{Li}_2(s) 
+
\operatorname{Li}_2\left(\frac 1s\right) 
\color{blue}{
-
\operatorname{Li}_2\left(\frac 1s\right)
-
\operatorname{Li}_2\left(\frac 1v\right)} 
+
\operatorname{Li}_2\left(\frac 1v\right) 
+
\operatorname{Li}_2(v) 
\\
&=
-\frac{\pi^2}6-\frac 12\log^2(-s)
-{\color{blue}{
\left(\frac{\pi^2}6 -\log\left(\frac 1s\right)\log\left(\frac 1v\right)\right)
}}
-\frac{\pi^2}6-\frac 12\log^2(-v)
\\
&=-\frac{\pi^2}2
-\frac 12(\log (-s) -\underbrace{\log(-v)}_{\log v-i\pi})^2
+(
\underbrace{\log s}_{\log(-s)-i\pi}
\log(v)
-
\log(-s)
\underbrace{\log(-v)}_{\log v-i\pi})
\\
&=
-\frac 12\log^2\frac{-s}v
\\
&=
-\frac 12\log^2\left(\frac 14(5+a)\right)
=
-\frac 12\left(\log\sqrt2 +i\arctan\frac{\sqrt 7}5\right)^2
\\
&=
\frac 12\arctan^2\frac{\sqrt 7}5-\frac 18\log^2 2 \qquad-\frac i2\log 2\arctan\frac{\sqrt 7}5\ ,
\\[3mm]
\operatorname{Li}_2(t) +
\operatorname{Li}_2(u) 
&=
\operatorname{Li}_2(\bar s) +
\operatorname{Li}_2(\bar v)
\\
&=
\frac 12\arctan^2\frac{\sqrt 7}5-\frac 18\log^2 2 \qquad+\frac i2\log 2\arctan\frac{\sqrt 7}5\ ,
\end{aligned}
$$
so the sum to be calculated is
$$
\operatorname{Li}_2(s) +
\operatorname{Li}_2(t) + 
\operatorname{Li}_2(u) +
\operatorname{Li}_2(v) 
=
\bbox[lightyellow]{\arctan^2\frac{\sqrt 7}5-\frac 14\log^2 2}
\ .
$$